# How to remove google maps header?

Tags: css, google-maps, iframe, maps, google-maps-markers

I have created my google maps via google maps , I have embeded to my website unfortunately it display a header which I dont want to be displayed.

hereL jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmenr28z/

[image]

Here is code:

```
<section class="map">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/embed?mid=11YLE4clSoswTweX22iXJALsg-GJkDc7s" width="100%" height="480"></iframe>
    </section>
```

I have tried to hide using css

```
.i4ewOd-pzNkMb-haAclf{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Ur right bro I have changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmenr28z/2/

The problem here is that you can't access the elements and styles inside an iframe. The easy hack is to set the wrapper to `overflow:hidden` and shift the iframe up a little to make the header invisible.

```
section.map {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
iframe {
  margin-top:-50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks perfect solution .